# Kotlin code - how does FlatMap work here?

Tags: kotlin, flatmap

The following is code from a LeetCode solution.

This is the description:

```
Given an array A of non-negative integers, half of the integers in A are odd, and half of the integers are even.

Sort the array so that whenever A[i] is odd, i is odd; and whenever A[i] is even, i is even.
```

I managed to write code that worked but mine was almost like Java but in Kotlin (a common problem - I know).

I found this code in the comments:

```
   fun sortArrayByParityII(A: IntArray): IntArray {
        val even = A.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
        val odd = A.filter { it % 2 == 1 }
        return even.zip(odd).flatMap { listOf(it.first, it.second) }.toIntArray()
    }
```

I know that the first couple of line do. They simple filter the array into even and odd arrays.
I even understand (after looking up) what the "zip" does.

What I can't figure out is what this does:

```
flatMap { listOf(it.first, it.second) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look step by step:

```
fun main() {
    val list = (1..10).toList()
    val even = list.filter { it % 2 == 0 } // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    val odd = list.filter { it % 2 == 1 } // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    val zipped = even.zip(odd) // [(2, 1), (4, 3), (6, 5), (8, 7), (10, 9)]
    val flatten = zipped.flatMap { listOf(it.first, it.second) } // [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
}
```

`flatMap` takes a function which returns a list and inserts elements of this list in to initial list. So `[(2, 1), (4, 3)]` becomes `[2, 1, 4, 3]`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that flatMap starts with an empty list and inserts into it the contents of the list returned by each call to the function. I assume that the "it" in this case is one entry in the zipped list.

Answer (score 0):

given the filtered lists:

```
odd = [1,3,5,7,9,...]
even = [2,4,6,8,...]
```

the zip function concatenates each single item of each list into a list of tuples:

```
even.zip(odd)
// [(2,1),(4,3),(6,5),(8,7),...]
```

flat map here is doing the operation on each item(tuple) and returns a single list, it picks first then second item in each tuple and adds them into a single list:

```
even.zip(add).flatMap { listOf(it.first, it.second) }
// [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
```